# How to listen to mic input and analyse in real time?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Hi unfortunately I've not been able to figure out audio on the iPhone. The best I've come close to are the AVAudioRecorder/Player classes and I know that they are no good fo audio processing.

So i'm wondering if someone would be able to explain to me how to "listen" to the iPhone's mic input in chunks of say 1024 samples, analyse the samples and do stuff. And just keep going like that until my app terminates or tells it to stop. I'm not looking to save any data, all I want is to analyse the data in real time and do stuff in real time with it.

I've attempted to try and understand apples "aurioTouch" example but it's just way too complicated for me to understand.

So can someone explain to me how I should go about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to analyze audio input in real-time, it doesn't get a lot simpler than Apple's [aurioTouch iOS sample app with source code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) (there is also [a mirror site](https://github.com/acekiller/iOS-Samples/tree/master/aurioTouch)).  You can google a bit more info on using the Audio Unit RemoteIO API for recording, but you'll still have to figure out the real-time analysis DSP portion.

The Audio Queue API is a slight bit simpler for getting input buffers of raw PCM audio data from the mic, but not much simpler, and it has a higher latency.

Added later: There's also a version of aurioTouch converted to Swift here: https://github.com/ooper-shlab/aurioTouch2.0-Swift

Comment: It does get simpler, I recommend you to use [Novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) and [NVDSP](https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP) (I'm the author of the latter)

Comment: Link in this answer is broken now.

Comment: @bartolsthoorn will you ever update the code for modern iOS & OSX??? 
It looks like an amazing project, but I can't use it with iOS 9 :(

Comment: @WillBrickner I am not really into iOS these days, but what are the incompatibilities specifically? NVDSP is a very minimal project, so I guess it shouldn't be too much work to update but I'm just very short on time right now.

Comment: My mistake, I was talking about Novocaine. So by extension your library probably doesn't work anymore either.

Comment: @WillBrickner Do you mean the copy of Novocaine bundled with NVDSP in the 'Examples' does not work anymore? I suppose the latest Novocaine (https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) still works for iOS 9, so just updating Novocaine should do the trick? My library is actually not limited to Novocaine, it simply works on raw audio data in arrays (it does not matter where it receives these from, Novocaine or otherwise).

Comment: @bartolsthoorn ah I see. No I was confused and I meant to say that Novocaine doesn't work for iOS 9 (at least not out of the box). I haven't used NVDSP yet.   P.S. It seems like there isn't a solid replacement for Novocaine and the guy hasn't updated anything in a couple of years. I really hope it gets some attention. Maybe someone will make a replacement?

Answer (score 2):

AVAudioPlayer/Recorder class won't take you there if you wanna do any real time audio processing. The Audio Toolbox and Audio Unit frameworks are the way to go. Check [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6) for apple's audio programming guide to see which framework suits your need. And believe me, these low level stuff is not easy and is poorly documented. CocoaDev has some [tutorials](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CoreAudioAndAudioUnitsTutorial) where you can find sample codes. Also, there is an audio DSP library [DIRAC](http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac2-iphone/) I recently discovered for tempo and pitch manipulation. I haven't looked into it much but you might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is samples with a minimum amount of processing by the OS, you probably want the Audio Queue API; see [Audio Queue Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AboutAudioQueues/AboutAudioQueues.html).

AVAudioRecorder is designed for recording to a file, and AudioUnit is more for "pluggable" audio processing (and on the Mac side of things, AU Lab is actually pretty cool).